# How do I stop my svgs from scaling/moving?

Tags: html, css, svg, iframe

I have this HTML which has a PDF file in it and 3 svgs that cover up the standard download, print, and three points at the top right. But when I zoom in or out the SVGs don't stay in position, they move and scale in size. (btw the pdf has to be an iframe for different reasons)

Is it possible to fix them to their position?

Here is how it looks without zooming:

[image]

and this happens when I zoom in:

[image]

```css
.div-icon {
  height: 36px;
  width: 36px;
  margin-top: 5%;
  margin-left: 10%;
}

.icon {
  filter: invert(1);
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
}

.icon-container {
  height: 40px;
  width: 150px;
  display: flex;
  z-index: 1;
  position: absolute;
  top: 18px;
  left: 1430px;
  background-color: rgb(50 54 57);
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<body>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/test.css">
  <div class="container">

    <div class="icon-container">

      <div class="div-icon">
        <svg viewBox="0 0 22 22" class="icon"><path d="M19 9h-4V3H9v6H5l7 7 7-7zM5 18v2h14v-2H5z"></path></svg>
      </div>
      <div class="div-icon">
        <svg viewBox="0 0 22 22" class="icon"><path d="M19 8H5c-1.66 0-3 1.34-3 3v6h4v4h12v-4h4v-6c0-1.66-1.34-3-3-3zm-3 11H8v-5h8v5zm3-7c-.55 0-1-.45-1-1s.45-1 1-1 1 .45 1 1-.45 1-1 1zm-1-9H6v4h12V3z"></path></svg>
      </div>
      <div class="div-icon">
        <svg viewBox="0 0 22 22" class="icon"><path d="M19 6.41L17.59 5 12 10.59 6.41 5 5 6.41 10.59 12 5 17.59 6.41 19 12 13.41 17.59 19 19 17.59 13.41 12z"></path></svg>
      </div>
    </div>

    <iframe style="position: absolute; height:100%; width:100%" src="/pdf/Doku.pdf"></iframe>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Change the value from pixels to vw, vh, vmin or vmax.
They will not get scaled 
And also do not write a 'left: a large number' to get your absolute positioned element to the right just use 'right: some value'
Try this:

```css
.div-icon {
  height: 6vmin;
  width: 6vmin;
  margin-top: 5vh;
  margin-left: 10vw;
}

.icon {
  filter: invert(1);
  height: 60%;
  width: 60%;
}

.icon-container {
  height: 8vmin;
  display: flex;
  z-index: 1;
  position: absolute;
  top: 3vmin;
  right: 3vmin;
  background-color: rgb(50 54 57);
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<body>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/test.css">
  <div class="container">

    <div class="icon-container">

      <div class="div-icon">
        <svg viewBox="0 0 22 22" class="icon"><path d="M19 9h-4V3H9v6H5l7 7 7-7zM5 18v2h14v-2H5z"></path></svg>
      </div>
      <div class="div-icon">
        <svg viewBox="0 0 22 22" class="icon"><path d="M19 8H5c-1.66 0-3 1.34-3 3v6h4v4h12v-4h4v-6c0-1.66-1.34-3-3-3zm-3 11H8v-5h8v5zm3-7c-.55 0-1-.45-1-1s.45-1 1-1 1 .45 1 1-.45 1-1 1zm-1-9H6v4h12V3z"></path></svg>
      </div>
      <div class="div-icon">
        <svg viewBox="0 0 22 22" class="icon"><path d="M19 6.41L17.59 5 12 10.59 6.41 5 5 6.41 10.59 12 5 17.59 6.41 19 12 13.41 17.59 19 19 17.59 13.41 12z"></path></svg>
      </div>
    </div>

    <iframe style="position: absolute; height:100%; width:100%" src="/pdf/Doku.pdf"></iframe>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but when I zoom in and out the svgs still move a little bit up and down, is there any way to fix this or is this as good as it gets?